# How to change number to letters using sed command?

Tags: linux, sed

How i can change numbers to letters by using sed command linux

for example :
if the longitude of numbers is  4 ,5 ,6 o 7 then change this number to abcd.(only sed)

123 1234 123445 125475585

result:
123 abcd  abcd abcd

Thanks

Comment: 4->a, 5->b, ... ? huh?

Comment: you'll probably have to clarify your question along with adding a few examples of things you tried in order to receive any help. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: where does longitude come from

Comment: its length mean if the number is more then 4 digits o 4 then change it to letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
echo '123 1234 123445 125475585' | sed -E 's/\b[0-9]{4,9}\b/abcd/g'
```

Output:

```
123 abcd abcd abcd
```

Comment: _The metacharacter \b is an anchor like the caret and the dollar sign. It matches at a position that is called a "word boundary". This match is zero-length._ [Source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Comment: and -E because i know -e

Comment: `-E` or `-r` or `--regexp-extended` enables [Extended Regular Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Extended-regexps.html).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the map operation.

```
$ sed 'y/4567/abcd/' <<< '65423476512935'
cba23adcb1293b
```